# Keyevent to click on Alert Dialog of Android screen

Tags: adb, android, android-alertdialog, monkeyrunner, key-events

Is there any way to simulate keyevent on "OK" or "CANCEL" buttons of Android dialogue box using adb commands?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One indirect way is:-

```
adb shell uiautomator dump /data/view.xml
adb shell cat /data/view.xml
```

calculate OK button coordinates from the relative coordinates given in the xml file.
Then do

```
adb shell input tap <x> <y>
```

Hope works.

Comment: uiautomator wont work in all the mobiles.For me it works in Galaxy S4 and not works in Galaxy S3

Comment: I have tried in almost all customer platforms except LG,It worked well.I am not sure about yours. Androidviewclient is another way.

Answer (score 3):

Using [AndroidViewClient/culebra](https://github.com/dtmilano/AndroidViewClient) you can simply do:

1. run `java -jar androidviewclient-2.3.25.jar culebra --verbose --verbose-comments --find-views-with-text=true --output=myscript.py`
2. edit `myscript.py` and add `vc.findViewWithTextOrRaise('Cancel').touch()` at the end (you can delete the unnecessary finds too)

Comment: What is the way if device is secure and we dont have the Application source code ? Is there any way to disable secure feature ?

Comment: Your options are described in https://github.com/dtmilano/AndroidViewClient/wiki/Secure-mode