# How get Css property 'color' from android device using Webdriverio

Tags: android, appium, webdriver-io

I'm using Appium and WebdriverIO to test Android device. But I couldn't use `alertAccept()` because it is not implemented in Appium 1.7.1, to click on "OK" button on Alert Message. 
How to close alert message ? May be there another ways to solve this problem.

Comment: did you check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17612315/keyevent-to-click-on-alert-dialog-of-android-screen

Answer (score 0):

Alert butts are inspectable on Android and they would have a locator similar to this:

- ID: `com.android.packageinstaller:id/permission_allow_button`
- XPath: `//android.widget.Button[@resource-id='com.android.packageinstaller:id/permission_allow_button']`

P.S. The above are for the accept/ok button. The reject/cancel button would have a locator with `permission_deny_button` instead of `permission_allow_button`